# XCode 4.5.1, Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I've upgraded my `XCode` to `4.5.1` in order to debug in my new iPad with `IOS 6.0.1`.
After that I get this error on console after compiling:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

And my application enters in a screen different from the main and the buttons do not work at all.

In the older version of `XCode` it worked as a charm.

Any ideas of what is happening?

On the app delegate I have this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.


    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

***Just to update, the only way I could get my app again was to delete Xcode 4.5.1 and go back to Xcode 4.4.1. There seems to be a problem in the .xib file and interface builder cannot link properly the objects in the newest versions. I don't know why***

A funny fact, before I updated the XCode i could not run my app on the ipad with ios 6.0.1(I was compiling for IOS 5.1)
After the downgrade it works.

Comment: You could post the lines in didFinishLaunching in your app delegate for starters...

Comment: There are [quite a few questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Applications+are+expected+to+have+a+root+view+controller+at+the+end+of+application+launch) that cover this subject here on SO. Doesn't any of those answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to AppDelegate class and add:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Comment: Why is this voted down? Without any further information from TS, this sounds like a reasonable answer.

Comment: I've have seen this on another question, but the problem is that even doing that it won't work. I don't know why.

Comment: Make sure self.viewController is not nil. This needs to be a reference (i.e., IBOutlet to your root controller).

Comment: @Zoukar: where did you add this line ? add this line before calling `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: Yes i've called it before [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];. I've also double checked to see if the viewController was correctly referenced on the Interface Builder.
I have the same results.

Comment: just one more tweak: write these codes too `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. For some reason my Xcode gets another view and get stuck in it. That message continues to appear.

Comment: after allocating the window and viewController you are getting the same issue ? I think then there will be some issue with the viewController code

Comment: Yes after that,  I was debuging the viewController to see if there was a problem, but apparently it is working fine... This app has like one year and worked flawlessly until I upgraded the Xcode.

Comment: The only way to solve my problem was to downgrade Xcode to the previous version.

Comment: that's not a good way, anyway happy to know that the issue is solved

Comment: It is not a good way, but I can maintain the code until I find out what happens on Xcode 4.5.1