# root view controller when upgrading app to ios 6

Tags: ios, ios4, ios6, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XCode 4.5.1, Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232209/xcode-4-5-1-application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at)

I'm a total noob in IOS app developing.

I use Xcode 4.5.1 with no storyboard.

I'm upgrading an IOS 4 app  because it fails to run correctly on IOS 6 devices. 
main view containing a question and five answers run once and stops there after user commit by pressing a button with the wanted answer, it should then reload itself with a new question and a new set of questions.

I get the infamous "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" in log output.

I've read and tried all comments and solutions in [7520971](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7520971) but to no avail... still getting error and it seems to prevent me to load the view correctly.

here's what in my appDelegate.h

```
/*
 *  AnimViewAppDelegate.h
 *  AnimView
 *
 *  Created by Administrateur local on 11-01-19.
 *  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
 *
 */


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootNavigationController.h"

@interface PPScaleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    RootNavigationController *RootNavigationViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootNavigationController *RootNavigationViewController;
@end
```

my appDelegate.m

```
//
//  AnimViewAppDelegate.m
//  AnimView
//
//  Created by Administrateur local on 11-01-19.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PPScaleAppDelegate.h"
#import "QuestionView.h"

@implementation  PPScaleAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize RootNavigationViewController;

//- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //Create the main screen
    //CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; //2012


    //Create the main view controller
    RootNavigationViewController = [[RootNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];
    //[window addSubview:RootNavigationViewController.view];

    [self.window setRootViewController:RootNavigationViewController];

    //Show the main window
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

.h

```
//
//  RootNavigationController.h
//  IPhonePPS
//
//  Created by Administrateur local on 11-02-11.
//  Copyright 2011 Le Groupe CDGI Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "QuestionView.h"
#import "ResultView.h"
#import "ResultTableView.h"


@interface RootNavigationController : UINavigationController {

    QuestionView *QuestionViewController;
    ResultView *ResultViewController;
    ResultTableView *ResultTableViewController;

}
@property(nonatomic, assign) QuestionView *QuestionViewController;
@property(nonatomic, assign) ResultView *ResultViewController;
@property(nonatomic, assign) ResultTableView *ResultTableViewController;

-(void)switchToResultMode:(QuestionPath *)QuestionPath;
-(void)switchToResultTableMode;
-(void)switchBack:(BOOL)Reset;
@end
```

.m

```
//
//  RootNavigationController.m
//  IPhonePPS
//
//  Created by Administrateur local on 11-02-11.
//  Copyright 2011 Le Groupe CDGI Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootNavigationController.h"

@implementation RootNavigationController
@synthesize QuestionViewController, ResultViewController, ResultTableViewController;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code.
        QuestionViewController = [[QuestionView alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];
        ResultViewController = [[ResultView alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];
        ResultTableViewController = [[ResultTableView alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];

        //Set the navigation bar hidden
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

        //Push the question view on the stack
        [self pushViewController:self.QuestionViewController animated:YES];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)switchToResultMode:(QuestionPath *)QuestionPath {
    [self pushViewController:ResultViewController animated:YES];
    [ResultViewController setQuestionPath:QuestionPath];
}

-(void)switchToResultTableMode {
    [self pushViewController:ResultTableViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void)switchBack:(BOOL)Reset{
    if(Reset){
        if([self.viewControllers count] == 3){
            [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }else {
            [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        [QuestionViewController resetAnswers];
    }else {
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

//-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
//  if([self visibleViewController] == self.ResultTableViewController || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
//      return YES;
//  }else {
//      return NO;
//  }
//}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

@end
```

spent two complete days trying to debug this but I give up and would really appreciate your help with this issue

PR

Comment: please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232209/xcode-4-5-1-application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at/13232244#13232244

Comment: Check if RootNavigationViewController is nil with the debugger, maybe there is something wrong with loading your RootNavigationController.

Comment: Your variable naming scheme is rubbish. Do not (NEVER) name an instance identical to a class. Instead of ` RootNavigationViewController = [[RootNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];`, do `rootNavigationViewController = [[RootNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];` - mind that capital R.

Comment: can you post at least some of your RootNavigationViewController code? it looks like it will be nil, maybe you need to use/create an init method?

Comment: updated with RootNavigationController view

Comment: @Till I get "Use of undeclared identifier...", should I change this elsewhere ?

Comment: It would be better to just use [[alloc] init] if you don't have a nib.

Comment: if I zip my project, can someone have a quick look over it ? the complete app run except a view that load but doesn't show. must be stupid because it worked well in previous IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to just use [[alloc] init] if you don't have a nib for your navigation controller. Also, your navigation controller should be initialized with its own rootViewcontroller. I don't know which one you want to be first, but it should look something like this:

```
  MyFirstViewControllerClass *rootVC = [MyFirstViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
  RootNavigationController *nav = [[RootNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
  self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Comment: if I zip my project, can someone have a quick look over it ? the complete app run except a view that load but doesn't show. must be stupid because it worked well in previous IOS.

Comment: @please_reboot, sure, I'll take a look at it. rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: thank you for your precious time !!!

Answer (score 1):

You should init your RootNavigationController with a rootViewController first :

```
[RootNavigationController initWithRootViewcontroller:QuestionViewController];
```

You can find this from the `UINavigationController reference` :

> Because the UINavigationController class inherits from the
>   UIViewController class, navigation controllers have their own view
>   that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a
>   navigation interface, you must install this view as the root of
>   whatever view hierarchy you are creating.

For instance, in `-(void)switchBack:(BOOL)Reset;` you popToRootViewController without even having set it.

Comment: Instead of [self pushViewController:self.QuestionViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `[self.window setRootViewController:RootNavigationViewController];` Notice - setRootViewController. It wants a viewController. Your RootNavigationViewController is a NavigationController as referenced here `@interface RootNavigationController : UINavigationController` not a viewController.

It looks like you should do something like this

```
RootNavigationViewController = [[RootNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window addSubview:RootNavigationViewController.view];
```

(referenced from [Programmatically build / navigate a Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241923/programmatically-build-navigate-a-navigation-controller))

I'm not sure if using

```
[self pushViewController:self.QuestionViewController animated:YES];
```

in the RootNavigationViewController is the same as doing something like this

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

But that should point you in a good direction to debug your issue.